# Automatically logging with some other user if open service console with system admin

Tags: lightning, user, service-cloud-console

System Admin is automatically logging with some other user when we a=try to open lighting service console.

and getting error : "We're sorry to report that something has happened to your session. Log in again, or return to the page to copy any unsaved text.
"

And it will automatically logged in with other user and it keeps loading the page.

We cleared all the cache and history and tried different browser as well.

What could be reason, or anything needs to be changed at the user level ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Salesforce, force closed all the opened tabs from back end for the affected user, so it works.